# How to make raw data from descriptives?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a table of descriptives, but I'd like to generate the raw data so that I can run stats like t.test and whatnot.

```
# Table. Heart rate between groups
#             Mean heart rate           sd     n
# Group1                125             11    218
# Group2                133             12    156
```

I'd like to fill in the remainder of group 2 with NAs so the vectors are the same length. Then, I'd like to run a t test to see if the two groups are different. I've been hacking away at it, but I can't seem to get everything working properly.

I was using norm, I'm just not sure how to then get that into a suitable format for stats:

```
group1 <- rnorm(n=218, mean = 125, sd = 11)
group2 <- rnorm(n=156, mean = 133, sd = 12)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "fill the remainder of group 1 with NAs" ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant group 2, in order to make both groups have a length of 218. Not sure if that's even necessary, though.